# Serving content to authenticated users

Tags: design, architecture, authentication, storage, cloud

I'm wanting to store lots of data in cloud storage - like S3.

I want some data to only be accessed by authorised users, one way I could do this is to authenticate the user on my service, download the data from the cloud to my server, and serve the data to the user. This seems innefficient - as my server has to both upload/download the content.

I'd rather the user directly download the data from the cloud - is there a standard technique for handling this?

---

I was hoping maybe there was a way to hook in my Oauth2 provider to my cloud storage so they can easily authenticate downloads - cant find anything like this. Maybe I'll use short-lived pre-signed URLs, that I'd have to generate for every download

Comment: I did this ages ago and back then the only way was to do as you described. An api with access wrapping the s3 store

Comment: @Ewan I'm thinking about rotating cached pre-signed download urls. Updated every hour or so, to minimise sharing/piracy

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with a small window where anybody who gets a specific "secret" URL can download the content, you can use [presigned S3 URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). If you're not happy with that, you probably want to think about whether you should be sharing the content to your users at all.

> This seems innefficient - as my server has to both upload/download the content.

Oh no! Is this *really* an issue for you though - are your servers bandwidth limited? If not, why are you worrying about this?

Comment: Because I will have to pay egress fees to my cloud storage provider, as well as ingress ***and*** egress fees to my server provider. Bandwidths never free - both in terms of money and time

Comment: I was hoping maybe there was a way to hook in my Oauth2 provider to my cloud storage so they can easily authenticate downloads - cant find anything like this. Maybe I'll use short-lived pre-signed URLs, that I'd have to generate for every download

Comment: That's an issue only if you're not running your servers in the same cloud as your block storage. The synergies of doing that _usually_ outweigh everything else.

Comment: `you probably want to think about whether you should be sharing the content to your users at all` what do you mean by this? Some security issue?

Comment: You've allowed the "sensitive" data onto a machine controlled by someone other than you; therefore you no longer control the data.

Comment: I can never fully avoid piracy. That doesn't mean I should just do nothing about mitigating it. There's definitely a level of mitigation that makes it not worth someone's time.